# Count entered numbers which are separated by space

Tags: java, string, count, split, java.util.scanner

I can't figure out how to deal with a following problem.

I have a input for user where they can enter various numbers which are separated by a space e.g. (20 30 89 ..)
I than need to count how many numbers were entered (in this case 3 numbers were entered)
How would I do this?

I assume logic behind this is something like count number of spaces and add 1 to it (the initial number which has no space in front of it), but I'm not sure how to do this via code.
It would also be nice to check if space was entered before first number and if it was than don't add + 1 to final count, also check for things like double spaces, triple spaces etc and count them as one space. Finally see if there is no space at the end (so it doesn't add up).

Here is what I've got so far (input for user):

```
package temperature;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author --
 */
public class Histogram {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Input for grades
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter temperatures below (separated by spaces e.g. 20 30 89 ..)");
        int temperature = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could add the numbers to an array or list and check the size of the list. or simply increment a counter when read a new int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only count the spaces, you could end up with any junk data going through as numbers.  What I would suggest is reading all the input until you reach a space character.  Then try to convert that to an Integer (or Double) if the conversion fails, do your error handling for invalid inputs, otherwise increase the counter.

An example would be something like this:

```
// Sample input used.
    String input = "23 54 343 75.6 something 22.34 34 whatever 12";
    // Each number will be temporarily stored in this variable.
    Double numberInput;
    // Counter used to keep track of the valid number inputs.
    int counter = 0;
    // The index directly after the number ends.
    int endIndex = 0;
    // Now we simply loop through the string.
    for (int beginIndex = 0; beginIndex < input.length(); beginIndex = endIndex + 1) {
        // Get the index of the next space character.
        endIndex = input.indexOf(" ", beginIndex);
        // If there are no more spaces, set the endIndex to the end of the string.
        if (endIndex == -1) {
            endIndex = input.length();
        }
        // Take out only the current number from the input.
        String numberString = input.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
        try {
            // If the number can be converted to a Double, increase the counter.
            numberInput = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
            counter++;
        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // Some error handling.
            System.err.println("Invallid input: " + numberString);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total valid numbers entered: " + counter);
```

Output:

```
Invalid input: something
Total valid numbers entered: 7
Invalid input: whatever
```

EDIT:  Apologies, I had the answer window open and did not see the other replies.  The split function should do perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

- Just read the complete line using `Scanner#nextLine()` method.
- Split the read line on one or more `spaces` - use `+` quantifier for
  that
- and then get the length of the `array` obtained.

Here's an example: -

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    int totalNumbers = scanner.nextLine().split("[ ]+").length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by space and count the number of elements:

```
    System.out.println("20".split (" ").length);
    System.out.println("20 30".split (" ").length);
```

This will print 1 and 2 respectively.

Here is a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/zlEzPj) for it.

Comment: I did System.out.println(grades.split(" ").length);   and I get error saying: int can not be dereferenced

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's a little longer than solutions that use the Split method but it will include only numeric values in the result. So for the following input:

```
12 32 234 555 24 sdf 4354 dsf34r34 rfedfg 4353
```

the function will return the following values in an array:

```
12
32
234
555
24
4354
4353
```

Here is the function:

```
private static String[] getWholeNumbers(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        output.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
}
```

If you only need the count, the function could easily be changed to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could take the input as string and then retrieve numbers from the string.

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String st=input.nextLine();
String[] split=st.split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<>();
String regex="^[0-9]+$";
     for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
     {
         if(split[i].matches(regex)) temp.add(Integer.parseInt(split[i]));
     }
```

Now you got all the temparatures as an `ArrayList<Integer>`